# How to show equality $A = (A\setminus B) \cup (A\setminus C) \cup (A \cap B \cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need help with proving that:
$$\tag{1}A = (A\setminus B) \cup (A\setminus C) \cup (A \cap B \cap C).$$

I started first with $2$ sets I showed that $A = (A\setminus B) \cup(A\cap B)$ like this:

1. $A \cap U$
2. $A \cap(\overline B \cup B) $
3. Distributive Law $\Rightarrow(A\cap\overline B) \cup(A\cap B) $
4. Using $(A\cap \overline B) = A\setminus B$ I got $(A\setminus B) \cup (A\cap B)  $

Now I tried to show, with same rules used up there, for sets $A,B,C$ that (1) holds. But the expression got ugly and I got stuck.

I tried to show with inclusions that 2 sets are equal:

1. $(\supseteq)$ is trivial, because for each of the 3 sets in the RHS has $x \in A$.
2. $(\subseteq)$ Let $x\in A$. I "split" set $A$ in two cases. First I assumed that $x\in A \setminus(B\cup C)$. Then since $A \setminus(B\cup C)\subseteq A\setminus B$, we have
   $$x\in (A\setminus B) \cup (A\setminus C) \cup (A \cap B\cap C) .$$
   Second case was $x\notin A \setminus(B\cup C)$. Then $(x\notin A) \lor (x\in (B\cap C))$. $x\notin A$ is contradiction, so $x\in (B\cap C)$ and with that $x\in (A\setminus B) \cup (A\setminus C) \cup (A \cap B\cap C)$.

Can I split $A$ in two cases like I did and if someone could hint me how to start with showing equality using laws because I want to know both ways.

Comment: Just Draw A Venn Diagram (TM)

Comment: need proof, Venn Diagram is not acceptable

Comment: Venn diagrams can be converted into proofs. If you've ended up colouring in all of $A$ on your diagram, just write down why you know you've coloured in all of $A$, and that's your proof.

Comment: i won't get points on exam with just Venn diagram, need logic proof

Comment: I restate: If you've ended up colouring in all of $A$ on your diagram, just write down why you know you've coloured in all of $A$, and that's your proof.

Comment: hi amWhy, first of all this is my first post on stack exchange and so it looks like it is, second my intention was not to be rude or expect some to just solve it for me, but to try me help understand. Yes, my sentence i wont get points on exam, means: I'm learning home for exam, and i cant just draw venn diagram and tell: "ok sets are equal". i need to show it by inclusions, otherwise they wont accept it. im currently on this problem for hour, because i coudnt solve (logic problem?) $ A = ..... = ( A \land \lnot B) \lor (A \land \lnot C) \lor (A \land B \land C) $ so i decided to ask for help.

Comment: So because its my first post i did not include my work on this problem. I know that $A = A \land ( \lnot B \lor B) = (A \land \lnot B) \lor (A \land B)$ so that proves it for 2 sets, but i get stuck in problem for sets A,B,C when i try to show my problem in title. so i tried the same logic ˘$A = (A \land \lnot B) \lor (A \land \lnot C) \lor (A \land B \land C)$ but i cant shorten it to just A. i try set algebra but im always stuck with $\lnot B$ or $\lnot C$

Comment: It looks like you are confusing propositional logic, with sets.  What I think you can do is use such logic as follows: It is sometimes referred to as "element chasing": Show that if $x \in A$ then*  $\Big((x \in A \land x \notin B)$ or $(x \in A \land x\notin C) $ or $(x \in A \land x \in B \land x \in C)\Big)$, and vice-versa.  For two sets, say $P$ and $Q$, to prove $P = Q$, we need to prove that $P\subset Q$ and $Q\subset P$, or in "element chasing," $x \in P \to x\in Q$ and $x \in Q \to x\in P$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align} & x \in\Big((A\setminus B) \cup (A\setminus C) \cup (A \cap B \cap C)\Big)\tag{given} \\ \\
&\iff x \in (A\setminus B) \lor x \in (A\setminus C) \lor x\in (A\cap B\cap C)\tag{1}\\ \\
&\iff (x\in A \land x \notin B) \lor (x \in A \land x \notin C) \lor (x \in A \land x \in B \land x\in C)\tag 2\\ \\
&\iff x \in A \land\big( (x\notin B \lor x\notin C) \lor (x \in B\land x\in C)\big)\tag 3\\ \\
&\iff x \in A \land \big({\lnot (x\in B \land x \in C) \lor  (x \in B \land x \in C)} \big)\tag 4\\ \\
&\iff x\in A \land \underbrace{((x \notin B\cap C)\lor (x\in B\cap C))}_{\top}\tag 5\\ \\
&\iff x \in A \land (\top) \tag 6\\ \\
&\iff x\in A\tag 7
\end{align}$$
$$ $$
Note this proof is bidirectional.  From $1 \to 2\to 3 \to 4 \to 5\to 6 \to 7$, and $7\to 6\to 5 \to 4 \to 3\to 2 \to 1$

In (2), we unpack the definitions of setminus (twice), and of set intersections.

In (3), we use the distributive property.

In (4), we use the DeMorgan's

In (5), $\top$ is essentially "necessarily/always true"  because it is always true that any element is either in or not in any given set.

Comment: Hello, could you please show Step 3) in more detail? I can not see how exactly the distributive law leads to this. Thank you